# Is putting # in href the "right" way to do an HTTP POST from the onclick event?

Tags: jquery, html, ruby, http, sinatra

I've seen many examples that put # in the href attribute of a link, in order to get the browser to fire the onclick event. I did this myself recently in a Ruby Sinatra application. What I'm noticing now is when I redirect to '/' from inside my server-side code (via a 303 response), the URL in the browser still has the # on the end.

Is this the "correct" way to do a post without a form element?

```
<a href='#' onclick="$.post('/test1/69')">add</a>
```

Comment: jeremy , if you don't have a seo requirement use div for handling click events and use return false...

Comment: Don't use a div. It isn't keyboard focusable (except with HTML 5 stuff that isn't universally supported).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preference is to have the click event fire a method that does the post and also returns false, preventing event propagation that would cause the link to actually be followed.  When you do this, it doesn't matter what you put in the href, because it won't be used.

Comment: Except when the user's Javascript is turned off... :-)

Comment: True.  The followup, as David Dorward says, is that the link ought to accomplish the same result as the javascript does (i.e. submit the form without ajax).

Answer (score 6):

The correct approach is to use [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement). You should [build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/).

In this case the best approach would probably to be to start with a `<form>` containing a submit button. Then style them to look the way you want (so the form is inline and the button is like a link). Then add a `submit` handler with [unobtrusive JS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) to AJAXify it.

Comment: -1 I strongly disagree with the form method for a simple button.  The "newer" way of doing it would be a button element styled via jQuery's button feature with a .click dom listener to fire the event.  Random forms everywhere for the purpose of a simple button is just adding unnecessary markup.  See http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/styling_buttons_and_toolbars_with_the_jquery_ui_css_framework/

Comment: This isn't a form for the purpose of a simple button, this is a form for the purpose of making a POST request.

Comment: To clarify, if I was going to have a table of these links, you would have X individual form elements (one in each row)? Seems like overkill.

Comment: If you were going to have a table, then you could have a single form around the entire table, and then (in theory) a `<button type="submit" name="thingy" value="123">add</button>` (then you could bind the AJAXyness to the buttons). In practise you would need to support Internet Explorer so http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/forms/multiple-submit-buttons.html

Answer (score 0):

That is very old way of doing you can probably do like this

```
<a class="test">add</a>

$('.test').click(function() {
 //you can do your logic here and say 
  return false;//it will do both stoppropagation and event.preventDefault

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

I prefer divs if there are click events when compared to a hrefs

Comment: `a` tags without the `href` attribute behave [in strange ways](http://jsfiddle.net/9PctZ/).

Comment: @thirtydot, for seo purposes if we are using a href ,i think we shouldn't use a href clicks, we should go for div or span..